# How to control form load from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I want to control my form load event from another form.
my problem I create some `winform control` in `form1` runtime, but the creation will controlled by `form2`.

I will read some data from user in `form2` and when user enter specific text I will create winform control in `form1`.

I make some code to do that using `from1` to create `winform` control in runtime.

```
private TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        private Button btnAdd = new Button();
        private ListBox lstBox = new ListBox();
        private CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
        private Label lblCount = new Label();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(550, 550);
            this.Text = "Test Create form in runtime ";
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            this.btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.btnAdd.Text = "Add";
            this.btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 25);
            this.btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
            this.txtBox.Text = "Text";
            this.txtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 25);
            this.txtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);

            this.lstBox.Items.Add("One");

            this.lstBox.Sorted = true;
            this.lstBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 55);
            this.lstBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 95);
            this.chkBox.Text = "Disable";
            this.chkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 190);
            this.chkBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 30);
            this.lblCount.Text = lstBox.Items.Count.ToString() + " items";
            this.lblCount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 160);
            this.lblCount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 15);

            this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
            this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
            this.Controls.Add(lstBox);
            this.Controls.Add(chkBox);
            this.Controls.Add(lblCount);

        }
```

How make the same thing from form2 ?

Comment: using instance of Form1 in Form2 you can add, where are you confuse btw?

Comment: i try that but cant control the load event

Comment: when you create instance load will get called when form1 is loaded

Comment: ok, fine load called but how to control that ?

Comment: if you want to control that in ``InitializeComponent()`` definition find ``Form1_Load`` and comment line where it is registerting Load event

Comment: I have done an update to the answer, please check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which kind of 'Control' you need. However in multiple forms environment, communication between forms is trivial. There are many ways to do communicate, like one can be as

Create public properties of type `Form` in your Parent form,

```
public Form propForm1 {get;set;}
```

When on menu item click you open form1, store it's object to that public property.

```
var form1 = New yourchildformname();
form1.MdiParent = this;
propForm1 = form1; // Add this line.
form1.Show();
```

Now every time when you will click an other button to open the form2, you will have propForm1 object, which you can use to set some data on that form.

**EDIT:**
On form2, you can access controls of form1 as

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.parent.propForm1.txtUserName = "Yokohama";
}
```

Remember the above code is on form2. Also set 'access modifier' property of txtUserName from `private` to `public`.

Comment: Kind of control some textbox, button and combobox